C++ - managing external dependencies
I have a cmake c++ application that I package in docker.
Some external dependencies I simply install using apt install.
e.g apt install rapidjson-dev, then include in cmake with
find_package(RapidJSON REQUIRED)
However some libraries that I see on GitHub, doesn't have an apt install option.
What are the best practices to manage packages in c++ projects, beside copying the library source code into my codebase? (something I prefer not to do).
Also using apt install is good for docker, but creates a bit of pollution for a developer machine.
In Python, libraries are fetched at build time (with pip install) and I can also have isolation between projects with virtualenv. I'm looking for something similar in c++.
I prefer a method that will be the same for docker and non-docker environments.

"What are the best practices to manage packages in c++ projects" - There is no "best" practicy. Aside from distro-specific package manager, there are vcpkg, Conan and other platform-independent package managers. There is FetchContent module in CMake which allows to automatically download the package when configure a project, so you will be able to build the downloaded package as a subproject.

Many well-known C++ projects support cmake and install command. You can consider installing your dependencies using cmake install on docker images even though they're not found from apt command.

Also, consider linking your dependencies with static libraries if you want to support running your application both on docker and non-docker envs. However, there're many projects which do NOT support static build or too huge to link in static libs.

First of all, C++ is a programming language, not a development environment. It simply doesn't care about these kinds of problems.
The following isn't really an answer -- but comments just aren't big enough. It's a bit of what I'm doing, mixed with a bit of thought process.
I don't know "best practices"; I simply mix various practices depending on the library at hand. Allow me to give you a few examples from my current project:

Externally maintained packages:

boost: installed into the system for Linux, nuget package on Windows
openssl: installed into the system for Linux, vcpkg package on Windows (still doesn't work 100%, might change)
protobuf: installed into the system for Linux, vcpkg package on Windows

Note that VisualStudio is more aware of the distinction between a development-environment and the actual system, so I don't need to install libraries into the system.
This works okayish on Windows because I could find packages that VisualStudio can use; for Linux, there's literally a ReadMe file that tells you what you need to install -- which you might have to adapt to whatever Linux you're using, since two Linuxes are never the same.
The big advantage is that I don't have to worry about building stuff. Which is often a huge mess on large libraries, with lots of obscure procedures to follow, prayers to make, and more tools to install. So I definitely want to avoid doing this.

Copied into my source tree (I tend to have a "Download.sh" in my repository that knows how to download, unpack, edit, and which files I want where so I can update it occasionally):

MagicEnum
ProtoPuf
One of the boost example sources

Note that I copy these files because the libraries are tiny and don't change much anyway; having them in MY repository guarantees they'll never go away. Also, I can just edit them a bit if needed during the download -- like the boost example: while it's giving a header, it's actually broken and doesn't work as given.
The libraries don't need building, and even if they did it would probably be reasonably easy since they are just small libraries. "Open Source" likes to overcomplicate things, but even if they were using something like configure, I might be able to just hardcode the results (since configure doesn't work on Windows anyway).
Also note that copying code into my repository means it's not going away, no matter what. And I can actually edit it a bit -- I like to avoid doing that if possible, as the edit might fail on a future version, but the option is there.

Git modules:

other code from me that I keep in separate repositories
protobuf ".proto" files created by a third party

Note that I could just as well have copied stuff into my repository. For my own submodules, it's rather obvious that I didn't do that, because I WANT to keep them separate in case I'm going to use them in other projects (or someone else could, but I don't expect that).
For the proto files, that's just a random decision I made -- I felt like just grabbing them from their repository when I do a checkout. Maybe in a few months I'll bump my head on the door and suddenly ask myself "why am I doing it that way, let's add a Download.sh and move it to my repository". There isn't always a clear preference.

These are pretty much the only ways I can think of anyway, and I'm using all of them in the same project.
